# c# asp.net repeater - create button based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

Basically what i would like to do is have a button which is only created for entries that have been flagged in a separate table for sending. So for example if i edit a record, i flag this other table and would like a send button to appear next to that record via the repeater below - is this possible? Can i do a check by calling a method for example unsure :(

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DepartmentsList" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
               <table id="grouptable" class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Send</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Last Modified</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sendSelect[]" value="<%# Eval("Dept_ID") %>"</input></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Dept_ID") %></td>
                        <td><a href="<%# Eval("gURL") %>"><%# Eval("DESC") %></a> </td>
                        <td><%# Eval("CHG_DATE") %></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="<%# Eval("gURL") %>"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> Edit</a><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send" /></td>
                        </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a check and inspect the current data record being bound to the repeater by using the [DepartmentsList_OnItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound.aspx) event.  It gives you all the power you need to dynamically change what's being bound and created in the repeater's item.

Comment: There's a decent example on the linked MSDN page.